# R-Code Loop-Bug

Tags: r, loops, error-handling

i have a little issue with running my R-script:

```
sensoren <- read.csv("C:/..../sensors.csv") 
messung <- read.table("C:/.../os.log")

s1 <- messung$V2
s2 <- messung$V4
s3 <- messung$V6
s4 <- messung$V8

i <- 1; j <- 1
while (i <= nrow(messung)){
+   while (j <= nrow(sensoren)){
+       if (s2[i] == sensoren[j,1] && s3[i] == sensoren[j,2] && s4[i] == sensoren[j,3]){ 
+           print(sensoren[j,5][drop=TRUE]); i <- i + 1; j <- 1;} else {j <- j + 1;}}}
```

Running the script I always get the error-message: Error in +while (j <= nrow(sensoren)) { : 
  invalid argument to unary operator

Hope someone can help me, thanks!!

Edit:

I changed my code and it looks like that now:

```
while (i <= nrow(messung)){
+   while (j <= nrow(sensoren)){
+       if (c(s2[i],s3[i],s4[i]) == c(sensoren[j,1], sensoren[j,2], sensoren[j,3])){ 
+           print(sensoren[j,5][drop=TRUE]); i <- i + 1; j <- 1;} else {j <- j + 1;}}}
```

But still the same error message...

Comment: Maybe check that your `sensoren` dataset has been loaded successfully. And you should try to vectorize your code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like nrow(sensoren) returns NULL, which nrow() does when its argument is not a matrix or a data frame. Check that the file read in as expected.

Also, I appreciate you didn't ask about this, but using nested loops isn't a very "R" way to do things because R is painfully slow at these operations. You may want to read up on merge(), apply() and vectorization in R.

Comment: hmm i don't think that's the case, after reading in the script nrow(sensoren) gives me back a value of 15 which is the right one. But I will follow your tip and will give myself a lecture about vectorization, although i don't realy know if it will solve my problem.

Comment: Could it be that you are really writing "+while" rather than "while"? The error message says "+while", which suggests this...

Comment: oh man, you are right, don't know why but it realy will be read "+while" by the compiler, after putting this line in the one above it works without errors.... -.-